# In sharepoint 2013, how to get the layout url of current page?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, popup

Recently i am migrated from SP2010 to SP2013 and i am trying to use the on demand js in pop ups. While doing that, i am facing an issue in getting an alternative for the following

```
var url = SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl(Path);
```

Can anyone help in getting the equivalent method/property in the sharepoint 2013 in Javascript for opening popup?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method remains the same in 2013, your problem could be that you do not request SP.js before calling the method.

Try this:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

function sharePointReady(){
    var url = SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl(window.location.href);
    /* DO YOU STUFF */
}
```

Comment: Sorry its not working.. getting "ReferenceError: SPUtility is not defined"

Comment: Sorry, missed that you where talking javascript

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: You are awesome dude.. i was nearby the answer and by the time you nailed it..

Comment: Any idea how to pass more than one function name in the SP.SOD.executeFunc?

Comment: My tip is to call one method like above, then let that method call your functions